# change default property in dnn registration form

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, registration

in dotnetnuke registration form , 'user name' , 'password', 'confiremation' and 'e-mail' are requierd. how is it possible to change their properties like other property in profile, for example email not requierd in registration form and become optional.

it is possible to modify

```
AddField("Email", String.Empty, false, PortalSettings.Registration.EmailValidator, TextBoxMode.SingleLine);
```

in core , is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Admin, Site Settings select the User Account Settings tab.

Choose Custom registration form type, and you can select the profile properties that appear on the form.  Alter the Required property of profile items to see what is required.

I believe that the minimum that you can get away with for registration is email, provided that you also set the option to use the email address as the user name.  You should also require a unique email address by editing web.config.

You can also use the options to require a valid profile for both registration and login.

No core changes are required.

(I should also mention that there are some third party modules that help you customize registration and login.  Google around an you will find them.)